# How to find the secret hash stored on a Python server?

Tags: python, linux, chatterbot

I am trying to configure the ChatterBot extension on the LiveHelperChat platform. The official instructions include the following step:

```
Edit extension settings in lhcchatbot/settings.ini.php
 set your 
"secret_hash"
"host"
```

Where do I find the secret_hash value? I am using shared hosting which is already running the Chatterbot application. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that when they say secret hash they are talking about a secret string that is used to sign cookies and things like that. If so it can be any good big string, as longs  as it secret. It

Comment: @geckos Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with LiveHelperChat specifically. However, services like this will often generate a hash for your account. Look for this in your profile or account settings. Otherwise, you will need to contact the service directly for any questions.